# CSS Modules in React.JS

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, css-modules, react-css-modules

I'm using version 3 of the create-react-app package. But my styles don't apply

```
import style from './App.css'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save your css file with `module` extention.

```
App.module.css
```

Then import it like this:

```
import style from './App.module.css'
```

Finally, apply your styles like this:

```
<div className={style.container}> Hello World! </div>
```

Comment: I get an error on the line className={style.container} ````Cannot find name 'style'.ts(2304)```` what do I do? Using React version 17.0.1

Answer (score 2):

Please read this link talking about adding a stylesheet to CRA.
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-stylesheet/

In summary, you should write `import './App.css'`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply styles easily to your existing code, you can use the [patch-styles](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-styles) package. See the example of usage in [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-patch-styles?file=src/App.js). It's introducing a more declarative way for applying styles you need to wrap your code with `<PatchStyles classNames={style}>` where `style` is the default import from the style module.

Answer (score 0):

For example we have to files like

**Button.module.css**

```
.error {
  background-color: red;
}
```

**another-stylesheet.css**

```
.error {
  color: red;
}
```

**How to Use? **

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styles from './Button.module.css'; // Import css modules stylesheet as styles
import './another-stylesheet.css'; // Import regular stylesheet

class Button extends Component {
 render() {
  // reference as a js object
   return (
     <div>
         <button className={styles.error}>Error Button</button> // Use 
          Module css 
         <button className="error">Error Button</button> //normal css 
         file
     </div>
   );
 }}
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess you just want to import and apply the styles, right?

If you want to just use the `css` you can just import it, like this:

```
import './App.css'
```

And it will be applied!

Comment: No. I want to use the css module.<button onClick={this.toggleHandler} className={style.red} >Toggle</button>

Answer (score -1):

Try this. 
`import './App.css';` 
add your code.